# What is the difference between [[Char]] and [Char] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Why do I need to use [[ ]] in this function?

Description: the function reverse all elements on the strings.

```
revStr :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
revStr ls = [reverse s | s <- ls]
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `Char` and `[Char]`?

Comment: `[Char]` is a list of `Char`'s - also known as a `String`. `[[Char]]` is a list of them. These are different types.

Comment: incidentally that function is (imo) better written as `revStr ls = map reverse ls`, or in pointfree style just `revStr = map reverse`

Comment: If all you want to do is reverse a *single* string, the type would be `[Char] -> [Char]`. This function reverses each string in a *list* of strings.

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: Simply playing with String (or [Char]) and [String] (or [[Char]]) could illuminate. There's no indication OP made even a tiny attempt to understand prior to coming to stackoverflow. Therefore, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 6):

`'a'` is a `Char`, a single character.

`['a','b','c']` is a string, a list-of-`Char`. This list can also be written as `"abc"`, using double quotes. Its type can be written as `String` or `[Char]`.

`["abc", "de"]` is a list of strings. Its type can be written as `[String]` or `[[Char]]` (list-of-lists-of-`Char`).

We could go on, and say that `[["abc","de"], ["ef", "abc"]]` is a `[[String]]` (list-of-lists-of-strings) or `[[[Char]]]`.

Your `revStr` takes as input not a single string, but a list of strings, hence the `[[Char]]` type. Its output is again a list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

- `Char` is a character, meaning a single symbol like `'A'`, `'$'` or `'3'`
- `[Char]` is a list of characters, also called a String (note `[Char] = String`) like `['A','$','3'] = "A$3"`
- `[[Char]]` is a list of lists of characters, (also `[[Char]] = [String]`). This is essentially a list of Strings like `["Hello", "World"]`

`revStr` reverses all Strings (or `[Char]`) in the provided List, thus its type is a list of Strings